# Can I run Java applets in Xcode?

Tags: java, xcode, terminal, applet

I am very fond of Xcode's GUI and code completion and would like to know if there is a way to run Java programs (more specifically applets) in Xcode 5 without using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans. I tried using the Xcode text editor and Terminal to run simple Java programs, but it wouldn't run an applet. Therefore, I wanted to know if you can somehow use Xcode's External Build System to run Java programs or (if that's not possible) run applets within Terminal.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `appletviewer`.  I should be installed within the same location as the JDK

Answer (score 0):

Applet Launcher (in /Developer/Applications/Utilities/) provides a graphical interface to Sun’s Java Plug-in. Applet Launcher loads an applet from an HTML page. For example, entering the following URL launches the ArcTest applet:

file:///Developer/Extras/Java/Applets/ArcTest/example1.html

Applet Launcher is useful for testing your applets in OS X. Performance and behavior settings for applets may be adjusted in the Java Preferences application installed in /Applications/Utilities.

Also see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/02-JavaDevTools/JavaDevTools.html) documentation